# Progress Tracker CSS - list items uneven

Tags: css, progress-bar

I have been utilizing [this](http://codepen.io/aniket/pen/whDqz) "Progress Tracker" CSS, but have been running into an issue where text (for each li element) that is longer than one line is making the progress tracker "unaligned". [See an example here](http://jsfiddle.net/smhdx6sv/).

One solution that I've tried is setting `overflow: hidden` on the li elements with long text, but that ends up hiding part of the text. Is there a better solution to keep the tracker aligned, even with progress points that have long text?

**CSS for the progress tracker:**

```
/* progress tracker */
.progress-meter {
    padding: 0;
}

ol.progress-meter {
    padding-bottom: 9.5px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
ol.progress-meter li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    height: 35px;
    width: 250px;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-bottom-width: 4px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    white-space: normal;
    margin-right: -6px;
}
ol.progress-meter li:before {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    text-indent: 0;
    left: -webkit-calc(50% - 9.5px);
    left: -moz-calc(50% - 9.5px);
    left: -ms-calc(50% - 9.5px);
    left: -o-calc(50% - 9.5px);
    left: calc(50% - 9.5px);
}
ol.progress-meter li.done {
    font-size: 12px;
}
ol.progress-meter li.done:before {
    content: "\2713";
    height: 19px;
    width: 19px;
    line-height: 21.85px;
    bottom: -36.95px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 19px;
}
ol.progress-meter li.todo {
    font-size: 12px;
}
ol.progress-meter li.todo:before {
    content: "\2B24";
    font-size: 17.1px;
    bottom: -36.95px;
    line-height: 18.05px;
}
ol.progress-meter li.done {
    color: black;
    border-bottom-color: yellowgreen;
}
ol.progress-meter li.done:before {
    color: white;
    background-color: yellowgreen;
}
ol.progress-meter li.todo {
    color: silver;
    border-bottom-color: silver;
}
ol.progress-meter li.todo:before {
    color: silver;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @rblarsen answer, I think going with absolute positioning for the anchor elements was the way to go, I added the following css to make the progress tracker line align properly:

```
ol.progress-meter a{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0%;
    white-space: normal;
    width: 250px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add this code:

```
ol.progress-meter li a {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-55%);
  width: inherit;
}
```

I believe your style should be as you want it :-)

**Edit:**
Changed `transform: translateX(-50%)` to `transform: translateX(-55%)` to make it more centered.